# Prevent flash cloning

Tags: arduino-nano, fuses

I need a way to prevent someone from cloning code from arduino. Without protection it can be cloned with advdudees in 2 min. I'm using atmega328p chip on nano. In this state arduino acts as a handshake for windows program i need to protect. There is nothing special or of value on arduino, but the custom handshake. One arduino for one .exe file. All arduino code is uploaded from arduino ide.

I did research and here it is.

1. Lock fuse bits. As i understood once locked flash and eeprom cant be read. When they are unlocked flash and eeprom are erased. I need one more arduino to act as programator.
2. Use some other unique hard to copy module like rfid card or bluetooth/wifi mac address. This is bad because it takes too much pins on nano.
3. Subtly solder 2 digital pins and set one to output and other to input. If not connected break loop.
4. Usb hardware dongle licence. I have no idea how to create one and it seems like some relic of the past. Custom file system or something...

I'd like to keep arduino nano for deployment.

There is no internet involved. If program had access to internet i'd just use db.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question? ... you provided a solution to the problem of preventing the copying of flash memory ... the handshake can only be protected by preventing physical access to the windows pc

Comment: I need to known if this is a good idea and would it work. I have one attempt to get it right. And if anyone has any better solutions.

Comment: So you are developing your own protection dongle. Well, why don't you simply use a proven product?

Comment: Note that setting the lock bits is pointless, while the Arduino bootloader is installed. The bootloader can still read out the program, even with the lock bits set. You'd have to remove the bootloader and upload the code using the ISP interface (ArduinoAsISP).

Comment: You could save a GUID in EEPROM that matches one in the compiled file. The sketch reads EEPROM, and compares the saved value, quitting if they don't match. This might require flashing a simple stand-alone sketch that only writes the EEPROM before flashing your main program. It's not skilled hacker-proof, but it would stop the unaltered sketch from running anywhere but the original MCU.

Answer (score 3):

Using the lock fuse bits is definitely the correct step here. Unlocking is not a problem, since the memory will be erased in that step and you cannot prevent reflashing anyway.

---

Very important note from Gerben in the comments:

> Note that setting the lock bits is pointless, while the Arduino bootloader is installed. The bootloader can still read out the program, even with the lock bits set. You'd have to remove the bootloader and upload the code using the ISP interface (ArduinoAsISP).

The lock bits only work for the ISP interface, which can be used to program the Arduino. The bootloader (which is part of the program on  the Arduino) still can read the program memory (it has to, since it is executed from there). Thus to prevent someone from reading out the program through the bootloader, you need to remove the bootloader. Programming is then done just like you are setting the fuses: Through ISP (for example via a second Arduino).

---

You didn't include details on the handshake. An important attack route would be to just sniff on the Arduinos Serial interface. Unless your handshake itself is encrypted locking the Arduino will not prevent attackers from getting it.

There are encryption libraries for Arduino (like [this one on github](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/crypto.html)). Based on your thread model and the needed resources (since the Uno is rather constrained especially in RAM) you can choose a fitting library and a fitting encryption algorithm. One important attack route would be a replay attack, where the attacker just resends the serial data, that he recorded in the last successfull transmission. One way to prevent that would be a rolling code (like modern garage door openers often use). Or you can create One-Time-Passwords (for example by combining the handshake secret with a timestamp and encrypting/hashing that; you need synchronized time for that).

Comment: Handshake works by sending 4 ints hardcoded in .exe. Those 4 ints are hardcoded on arduino, it connects if they match. Before sending i do some basic math operations and reverse them on arduino. Then i send multiple random numbers, do some math ℅ 6 = inc. One byte is one command so i increment command bytes on both sides by inc. Every time arduino connects command bytes are different. If attacker was only sniffing data, he would get random numbers and would need to find a pattern and reverse enginner math operations.

Comment: @gagicf2 That is better than transmitting the plain secret, though not impossible to reverse engineer the pattern. I think with a number of sniffed transmissions one could do a statistical analysis and guess the pattern. Though - as stated - it comes down to your thread model. You can decide, that this level of security is enough.

Comment: Instead of sending the secret (even obscured) generate a random nonce and send that instead. The Arduino hashes a stored secret concatenated to the incoming nonce, and returns that hash to the computer, which performs the same steps itself (the EXE knows the secret), and compares the two hashes to validate. In this role, you can even use something cryptographically weak but CPU cheap like sha1 or even md5, as long as your nonce is longer than 16 chars, or 24, or 32, whatever you need to sleep. Tiny stand-alone hash functions fit better into MCUs than a whole lib of crypto tools you don't need.